# Activity Not Responding half the times it is launched

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

Something strange here: my Activity half of the time it is launched freezes and i get an ARN from the system.

A while ago i wrote i simple game in AndEngine + PhysicsBox2d extension, without incurring in any ANR problem.
I spent last few days refactoring the code, introducing a couple of classes to handle start-up configuration and moving code to improve cohesion.
Ideally no change in behaviour was implemented.
however now if i open the app and close it normally, the second time I open it, the app freeze and get a force close for time out.
Here is the output from the log:

```
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138): ANR in mp.andreabarbadoro.mama (mp.andreabarbadoro.mama/.DaisyGameActivity)
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut 
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138): Load: 2.77 / 2.62 / 2.35
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138): CPU usage from 13439ms to 0ms ago with 99% awake:
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):   3.2% 116/akmd: 0.9% user + 2.3% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):   2% 1679/mp.andreabarbadoro.mama: 2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):   1.6% 138/system_server: 1% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 3 minor 1 major
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):   0.5% 228/com.android.launcher: 0.5% user + 0% kernel / faults: 57 minor
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):   0.6% 1697/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):   0% 67/yaffs-bg-1: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):   0% 1699/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138): 1.4% TOTAL: 1.2% user + 0.2% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138): CPU usage from 1542ms to 2104ms later:
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):   10% 138/system_server: 3.5% user + 7.1% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):     3.5% 173/InputDispatcher: 3.5% user + 0% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):     1.7% 149/SensorService: 1.7% user + 0% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):   3.5% 116/akmd: 0% user + 3.5% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):     3.5% 1694/akmd: 0% user + 3.5% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):   3.5% 1679/mp.andreabarbadoro.mama: 3.5% user + 0% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):     3.5% 1688/er$SensorThread: 1.7% user + 1.7% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138):   0.9% 1697/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
09-03 19:41:40.416: ERROR/ActivityManager(138): 10% TOTAL: 7.1% user + 3.5% kernel
09-03 19:41:50.756: WARN/ActivityManager(138):   Force finishing activity mp.andreabarbadoro.mama/.DaisyGameActivity
```

So, any idea where to start to look for this bug?

**edit:** 
after looking in the debug window for Activity.onDestroy method's breakpoint, i can see how after the activity dies android.hardware.sensormanager$SensorThread seem to bo still alive.
Is this the normal behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at /data/anr/traces.txt and refer to the main thread's stack trace. (assuming this file wasn't overwritten with new ANRs).

Comment: my ANR was a symptom of a subtle bug caused by my sub-optimal understanding of activity's lifecycle in multithread context. Your tip helped me isolate the deadlock  I ran into. Thank you for letting me discover something new!

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing on the onCreate method? It seems that you're doing some heavy stuff that should be handled in a different thread.

Without seeing the code it would be extremely hard to point you to the problem... So my best suggestion for now is to start a thread for the heavy tasks.
Consider showing a splash screen / Progress dialog until the thread finishes (you can use  AsyncTask for that)

Answer (score 0):

Remember what the ANR means: You are blocking the main/UI-thread for a certain time (5s, see [What Triggers ANR?](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html#anr)), so that input events can't be handled correctly.

So you are probably  doing some heavy work inside this thread, maybe executed from from `onResume()` or `onRestart()`. Start looking for these expensive operations and make sure you execute them in a seperate thread (e.g. via [`AsyncTasks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)). If you are not sure what is an expensive operation in your app, consider measuring with `traceview`. See [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/10/traceview-war-story.html) on the android developers blog for a nice introduction.